# How to use default values for references that do not have a match in php preg_replace function?

Tags: php, reference, preg-replace, default-value

## What I would like to do

In php, something like this:

```
$input = '23:10';
$pattern = '/^(\d?\d):(\d?\d)(:(\d?\d))?$/';
$rewrite = '$1h$2m$4s';

$output = preg_replace( $pattern, $rewrite, $input );
echo $output;
```

`$input` can be a time with or without the seconds, but without seconds it should return '0' as default for `$4` in the replacement string. So the output, which is now:

```
23h10ms
```

should be:

```
23h10m0s
```

## Important:

**For the solution it's really important that the input of the final function consists of an arbitrary `$pattern` and `$rewrite` string that transform the `$input` string to the output format. So no hard-coded checks for that seconds part, but really a general way of inserting a default value for references in the `$rewrite` string that refer to optional parts in the `$pattern` string. The function should also work for a case with (for example):**

```
$input = '3 hours';
$pattern = '/^(\d+) hours( and (\d+) minutes)?( and (\d+) seconds)?$/';
$rewrite = '$1h$3m$5s';
```

As this example illustrates, I have no control over the desired formats (`$pattern` + `$rewrite`), so they can vary quite a lot. Most important reason for this: input and output can/will be in other languages too and therefore `$pattern` and `$rewrite` are obtained from language files (Joomla).

## Possible direction to solution

The closest I have come so far is the following:

```
// Get a $matches array:
preg_match( $pattern, $input, $matches );

// Replace the references ($1, $2, etc.) in the rewrite string by these matches:
$output = preg_replace_callback(
  '/\$(\d+)/g',
  function( $m ) {
    $i = $m[1];
    return ( isset( $matches[$i] ) ? $matches[$i] : '0' );
  },
  $rewrite
);
```

Two things about this:
1. It does not work yet, because $matches is not available in the callback function.
2. It becomes very tricky using the rewrite string as input for preg_replace_callback().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

For the wanted functionality to be dynamic, I'd suggest writing a new class in which all needed information are attributes. Inside that class you can call `preg_replace_callback` with a member method and there check for the existence of all needed groups - if one does not exist, it shall be replaced with the defined `$defaultValue`.

```
class ReplaceWithDefault {

    private $pattern, $replacement, $subject, $defaultValue;

    public function __construct($pattern, $replacement, $subject, $defaultValue) {
        $this->pattern = $pattern;
        $this->replacement = $replacement;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->defaultValue = $defaultValue;
    }

    public function replace() {
        return preg_replace_callback($this->pattern, 'self::callbackReplace', $this->subject);
        //alternative: return preg_replace_callback($this->pattern, array($this, 'callbackReplace'), $this->subject);
    }

    private function callbackReplace($match) {
        // fill not found groups with defaultValue
        if (preg_match_all('/\$\d{1,}/i', $this->replacement, $values)) {
            foreach ($values[0] as $value) {
                $index = substr($value, 1);//get rid of $ sign
                if (!array_key_exists($index, $match)) {
                    $match[$index] = $this->defaultValue;
                }
            }
        }

        $result = $this->replacement;
        // do the actual replacement
        krsort($match);
        foreach ($match as $key=>$value) {
            $result = str_replace('$'.$key, $value, $result);
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

You'll need `krsort()`, so it doesn't mistake e.g. `$15` for `{$1}5`.

The class can now be used like this

```
$originalQuestion = new ReplaceWithDefault('/^(\d?\d):(\d?\d)(:(\d?\d))?$/',
    '$1h$2m$4s',
    '23:10',
    '00');
$updatedQuestion = new ReplaceWithDefault('/^(\d+) hours( and (\d+) minutes)?( and (\d+) seconds)?$/',
    '$1h$3m$5s',
    '3 hours',
    '0');

print "<pre>";
var_dump($originalQuestion->replace());
var_dump($updatedQuestion->replace());
```

And will produce the wanted result.

---

*original post*

I'm not sure if this can be done with a regular `preg_replace()`. However, PHP offers another possibility: [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback). When defining the function, you can use more complex logic.

```
$input = '23:10';
$pattern = '/^(\d?\d):(\d?\d)(:(\d?\d))?$/';

function correctFormat($hit) {

    if (isSet($hit[4]))
        $seconds = $hit[4];
    else
        $seconds = "0";

    return $hit[1]."h".$hit[2]."m".$seconds."s";
}

$output = preg_replace_callback( $pattern, "correctFormat" , $input );
echo $output;
```

---

I'd suggest a solution as shown by [Chinnu R](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007421/1557526), since a regex is obviously not necessary and has no advantages to a regular explode in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this is exactly the kind of answer I tried to avoid by the last paragraph of my question. I simplified the case to illustrate it here, but the actual situation is that I get a pattern and a rewrite (much more complex then my example) and I have to write a function that use both of them to convert the input value. So, using the rewrite string instead of hard-coding the format like you did behind `return`.

Comment: Btw. Nice choice of variable name `$hit`. Once you see that dollar sign as an 's' you can't read it normally anymore :)

Comment: I honestly didn't had that in mind when naming `$hit` ^^'' You can also dynamically return here, it is just a bit more complicated. Say your `$rewrite` string is fixed, you'd need a function that replaces `$1 => $hit[1], $2 => $hit[2]` etc. and can use the given string. But to do this in an elegant way will be complicated, I'd suggest the use of an individual class. Please update your example so it fits your needs and educate yourself in this matter - a snippet like this is fast to write, but we won't write individual preg_replace methods with complex logic.

Comment: I already tried something in the direction you just pointed. I added it to the question...

Comment: It still isn't clear (to me), why you need a more sophisticaed method to solve this than the ones posted are

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps you,

```
    $input = '23:10';     
    list($h, $m,$s) =  explode(":", date('H:i:s', strtotime($input)));    
    echo $h."h".$m."m".$s."s";
```

Another method;

```
    $input = '23:10';
    list($h, $m, $s) =  explode(":", $input);       
    if($s==""){ $s="00";};
    echo $h."h".$m."m".$s."s";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this is exactly the kind of answer I tried to avoid by the last paragraph of my question. I simplified the case to illustrate it here, but the actual situation is that I get a pattern and a rewrite (much more complex then my example) and I have to write function that use both of them to convert the input value. But with a default value of '0' for unmatched references.